# How to test MySQL case sensitivity using H2

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0, h2

I'm developing a Scala/Play application that uses mysql.  I've run into an issue where my application breaks when deployed to our integration environment because the sql queries from my application have the case wrong for tables and aliases.  I didn't catch this in development because I'm on a Mac where MySQL is case insensitive by default.  Beyond configuring my local environment to be case sensitive as well, I'd like the unit tests to fail when queries are written that have the case wrong.  I'm testing the database with H2 as described by the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithDatabases).  I set up the database with the following code where *schema* is a string that has the creation script:

```
def apply[T](block: Database => T):Unit = {
  Databases.withInMemory(
     urlOptions = Map(
       "MODE" -> "MYSQL"
     ),
     config = Map(
       "logStatements" -> false
     )
   ){
  database =>
    Evolutions.withEvolutions(database, SimpleEvolutionsReader.forDefault(
      Evolution(
        1,
        schema,
        ""
      )
    )){
      block(database)
    }
  }
}
```

Intuitively the config map would have an option like `"caseSensitive" -> true` or something like that but I've been unable to find documentation for all the options there.  Does someone know if H2 has a configuration option for this and what it is?

Answer (score 5):

That is explained by both [H2 docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) and Play docs (which are basically quoting H2 docs):

> In MySQL text columns are case insensitive by default, while in H2 they are case sensitive. However H2 supports case insensitive columns as well. To create the tables with case insensitive texts, append `IGNORECASE=TRUE` to the database URL (example: `jdbc:h2:~/test;IGNORECASE=TRUE`).

And from [Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Developing-with-the-H2-Database):

> Text comparison in MySQL is case insensitive by default, while in H2 it is case sensitive (as in most other databases). H2 does support case insensitive text comparison, but it needs to be set separately, using `SET IGNORECASE TRUE`. This affects comparison using `=`, `LIKE`, `REGEXP`.

So, you need to change your `urlOptions` to consider `IGNORECASE` parameter:

```
def apply[T](block: Database => T): Unit = {
  Databases.withInMemory(
    urlOptions = Map(
      "MODE" -> "MYSQL",
      "IGNORECASE" -> "TRUE"
    ),
    config = Map(
      "logStatements" -> false
    )
  ) {
    database =>
      Evolutions.withEvolutions(database, SimpleEvolutionsReader.forDefault(
        Evolution(
          1,
          schema,
          ""
        )
      )) {
        block(database)
      }
  }
}
```

But, I would advocate against using a different database engine when running your integration tests. Try to use the same database that is used in production since it will give your tests more confidence.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this documentation.  Unfortunately it's not quite what I was looking for.  As it says, the IGNORECASE option affects data in comparison but it doesn't seem to have any consequence for meta data such as table names and aliases.

Comment: Also, I agree with your advise regarding integration tests but that's not what this is.  It's just meant to help with unit tests which are often run in parts of our pipeline that don't have a MySQL instance readily available, such as the build/test trigger done on commit. Our integration tests are a little further down the pipeline and done with the actual MySQL driver.